# Center aligning image when resized?

Tags: html, css, image, resize, center

When I resized the "logo" as I wanted it, it does not longer align in center of the page, now it's in the left when I added those 2 last `.logga`.

So this is my code:

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOkRy.png);
    background-color: #cccccc;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:   cover;
}
.logga {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}

.logga img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="logga" align="center">
   <a href="/start"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOkRy.png" alt="Hello"></a>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It aligns to the center of the containing div. If you need the div to center. The parent element needs to have a `width` property and then the child element would need `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto;`.

Example fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8yhsr5ba/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with CSS by specifying `margin:0 auto;` for the `.logga` class.

```
.logga{
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

That lets the browser calculate even spacing on each side of the element automatically. Note: although deprecated, it could also be centered with HTML by using `<center></center>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class="logga" align="center">
                <a href="/start"><img src="logga.png" alt="Hello"></a>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. You'll get your image centered.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("bg2.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:   cover;
}
.logga {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  background-color:white;
}

.logga a{
  display:block;
}
.logga img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logga">
            <a href="/start"><img src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/62/6983929-fall-nature-photography.jpg" alt="Hello"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed background color too so it's totally transparent but thanks! Now it works

Answer (score -1):

The align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead, like this:

```
.logga {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* this places .logga in the center of the body */
    text-align: center; /* this centers inline elements inside .logga, you don't necessarily need it */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

just use margin:auto; in style.